# Alternatives to reading config files from class libraries at design time?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForm project that contains several UserControls.  This WinForm project has a reference to an assembly (lets call it `lib.dll`) that is created from another project (Class Library) that exists in a different solution.

Now, several of the `UserControls` make calls into `lib.dll` that return values from the `app.config` file.  At runtime `lib.dll` works fine and returns the necessary data but at design time, I am getting an exception from `lib.dll` because the `app.config` sections are `NULL` (the exceptions are by design).

Now I could go through each control and wrap any code that calls into lib with

```
 if(!DesignMode) { //code }
```

But that is a lot of controls to go and apply that to.  Is there something I can do globally that would be more elegant then testing the DesignMode property?

**Edit**

In response to the two comments left below: the solutions provided don't appear to work.  The assembly that is causing me a problem lives in the same directory as the app.config. The general directory structure looks like this

- References Folder
- Configurations (Folder)
- appsettings.config
- app.config
- lib.dll

`app.config` pulls in several other config files (`appsettings`, `cnx` strings, etc) which reside in the Configurations directory.  In the case of my exception the value I am trying to get resides in one of these ancillary config files that is referenced by `app.config`.

Comment: Have you tried adding a copy of the app.config file to the directory which contains the dll?  Just a hunch.

Comment: @Jeff is right, and you can do two things, you can make the app.config a link to the other project, then set it not to deploy with the dll (Build Type: None).

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Neither of your solutions work but I have updated my original post to possibly shed some more light on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. A solution could be to create in lib.dll a static class like this one :

```
public static class Config
{
    private static readonly _param1;

    static Config()
    {
        _param1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Param1"] ?? "Your default value";
    }

    public static string Param1
    {
        get { return _param1; }
    }
}
```

Then, in your code, insted of writing ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Param1"], you will use Config.Param1. So you won't need to test the property DesignMode.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do this, IMHO.

One thought that immedidately comes to mind would be to use an inheritance-based approach for the user controls in question? That way, in the base class, you can put that `if (DesignMode)` check in, and do the correct branching from there.

```
// if i were to visualizeyour lib.dll data initializer call like this:
class BaseUserControl
{
    // i'm guessing that you initialize the data somehow... 
    void InitializeData()
    {
        if (!DesignMode)
        {
            InitializeDataLocal();
        }
    }

    protected virtual InitializeDataLocal()
    {
        // whatever base behavior you want should go here.
    }
}

// in the derived classes, just put the code you currently have for 
// fetching the data from lib.dll here...
class UserControl : BaseUserControl
{
    protected override InitializeDataLocal()
    {
        // fetch from lib.dll...

        // optionally invoke some base behavior as well, 
        // if you need to...
        base.InitializeDataLocal();
    }
}
```